# How do avoid connection throttling in office 365 / EWS

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices

I run an app as service which uses an exchange service object. in the past this would be created once and used for as long as the app was active.
Recently I had to move to oAuth authentication which has the problem of a token that is only active for 65 minutes. So every 30 minutes i get a new token and authenticate the exchange service object again with that new token. (service.credentials = new OauthCredentials(result.token)
Now the issue comes up that the app is using to many connections according to the o365 throttling policy. I believe it's 27 connections max.

So is there a way to avoid this issue? Can I for example release the previous connection from the pool that o365 is holding? or can I maybe use something like a time out parameter like we can on pull subscriptions?

Thanks!
John

I have no idea yet other than renewing the token after an hour so it uses less connections. But this is not a fix

Comment: i get a new token and authenticate the exchange service object again with that new token. (service.credentials = new OauthCredentials(result.token) . Are you creating a new service object each time you renew the token? if so why ? that would change the underlying cookies which would most likely be the cause of the problem

Comment: Thanks for your reply Glen. No I only update the credentials of the service object so it uses the new token. 
Is there a way to tell exchange that it needs to release connections that it counts for it's throtling policy?

Comment: No but with concurrent connection limit you should really only be hitting that if you have multiple threads running against the server concurrently. It's more likely in those type of situations you hit the resource based limits because your essentially putting too much load on the backend. Is this Public Folders ? or is it a multi-tenanted app ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1229695/is-anyone-seeing-unusual-ews-throttling-requests maybe related seems like they might be fiddling with the backend.